# Excel VBA Copy Sheet without link to original sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel files; File_1 and File_2. File_1 has two sheets; Sheet_A and Sheet_B. Data from File_2 is transposed to Sheet_A (in File_1).

I have a vba code attached to a button in Sheet_B that copies data from Sheet_A into Sheet_B. The code works fine, but it keeps the links from File_1.

I would like to just copy the data and keep its formatting without keeping the links. How can I achieve this?

The part of my code that copies the data from Sheet_A into Sheet_B is below:

```
    ' Check the Record Sheet to ensure the data is not already there
    Set CheckForDups = recordSht.Range(recordSht.Cells(1, 1), recordSht.Cells(1, lCol)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

    ' If CheckForDups is Nothing then the date was not found on the record sheet. Therefore, copy the column
    If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy Before:=recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1)
```

Comment: between the text and code provided, the situation is very unclear.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've edited my post. Hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to paste values on destination:

```
If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then 
    maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy 
    recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End If
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks it works but it does not keep the formatting.

Comment: `xlPasteValuesAndFormats` - I think is the constant. Or add one more line `recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman is right. Please add one line: recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats